# Timer Class internals

Tags: .net

I would like to set a scheduler in order for a job to run approximately every 30 days. I was thinking of using a timer and either set a large interval or set a smaller interval and decrement an integer variable.

I was wondering, during this interval, how the computer actually checks if the interval time has elapsed. I thought that maybe the Timer class sets an end time and, periodically checks if the system time is greater than the end time.

Though I don't particularly find this method so productive, I was wondering if a more intelligent way exists.

Comment: This is fairly broad with not a lot of detail. I would look into existing tools that do this like windows task scheduler. For now I am going to vote to close the question.

Comment: The (rather academic) question at hand aside - why not simply use the Windows Task Scheduler to solve this? It will give you perfect control when to execute your process.

Comment: If you are curious, the .net `Timer` source code is available to look at here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,051a39d380760b26

Comment: You ought to be a lot more concerned about the reliability of your power company and your Windows Update deployment scheme.  The documented maximum value for the Interval property is Int32.MaxValue.  That's 24.8 days.  Using the built-in task scheduler is likely to be the real solution.

Comment: Guys sorry, maybe I phrased the question in a wrong way. I have no question on how to finally achieve the scheduling. During the search for a solution, I started wondering about how the interval is internally verified, and I made an assumption which I found costly. And I wanted to know, due to theoretical interest, how it works. @BradleyUffner Thanks for that link.